# I need to make py to exe. I'm using python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I need to make py to exe. I'm using python 3.5.2. 
Try to install pyinstaller for it. But didnt understand how it install it properly or how to use it?
I'm a beginner of python. Could someone please explaine in in very basic manner? Thank you for your time.

Comment: It would probably be wise to read and understand the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install pyinstaller with pip: **pip install pyinstaller**

If the installation is successful, try to create an exe with the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile [your_script].py
```

Update your question with the errors, if you get any.